# Error when installing Google Chrome on CentOS

Tags: centos, chrome

I downloaded the [32 bit .rpm](http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?platform=linux_fedora_i386) (For Fedora/openSUSE) to my CentOS machine. when installing it, I got the following error.

```
$ rpm -ivh google-chrome-stable_current_i386.rpm
warning: google-chrome-stable_current_i386.rpm: Header V4 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 7fac5991
error: Failed dependencies:
        lsb >= 3.2 is needed by google-chrome-stable-12.0.742.124-92024.i386
        libcurl.so.4 is needed by google-chrome-stable-12.0.742.124-92024.i386
        xdg-utils is needed by google-chrome-stable-12.0.742.124-92024.i386
```

This much is clear (I guess), that I need the package `lsb` version greater than or equal to 3.2, `libcurl.so.4` and `xdg-utils`. But where will I get these from. I think installing the three above packages should resolve the installation error.

*Addendum: Progress was made by installing the packages `lsb` and `xdg-utils` using the command `yum install <pkg_name>`. But I still have the `libcurl.so.4` library file as a missing dependancy. Any ideas as to how this can be resolved.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to use `yum`, which is the Redhat command-line package manager.

In this case, `lsb` and `xdg-utils` refers to rpm packages, which you can find in the Centos repos by typing `yum search <pkg_name>`. If you want detailed information about a package, you can use `yum info <pkg_name>`. Once you find the packages that you need in the repos, you can install them with `sudo yum install <pkgs>`.

`libcurl.so.4` isn't a package name, but rather a library file provided by some package, in this case libcurl. This can be determined by using `yum whatprovides <filename>`. Once you determine the package, you can install it as above.

Comment: When I use `yum whatprovides libcurl`, I get no matches found. But the good news is that the command to install the google chrome package now says I don't have only `libcurl.so.4`. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: @Thomas If you try to run 'yum localinstall google-chrome-stable_current_i386.rpm' does yum is able to resolve the dependencies?

Comment: @Thomas - I'm not sure why it didn't find it, but I tested it against a different repo.  You can run `sudo yum clean all` and then `sudo yum makecache` to rebuild the local yum database and try again. It's a good idea to do this periodically, anyways. However, the package you need is called `libcurl`. You can search/info/install it according to above instructions.

Comment: @Vitor Braga When I run `yum localinstall google-chrome-stable_current_i386.rpm`, I get `Error: Missing Dependency: libcurl.so.4 is needed by package google-chrome-stable-12.0.742.124-92024.i386` among other details and it doesn't resolve the library file dependency.

Comment: @Joe Internet ... after some research it seems that the command `yum whatprovides libcurl.so.4` will only work on a machine that already has the package that placed the libcurl.so.4 file in that machine. It is of no use on a machine that does not already have the file. I tried running the `sudo yum clean all` and then `sudo yum makecache` to rebuild the local yum database; but this did not help. I also attempted installing the package `libcurl` by using the command `yum install libcurl`, but it returned `No package libcurl available`. Any other ideas I could try?

Comment: CentOS/RHEL 5 does not have libcurl.so.4, but libcurl.so.3. So, this rpm requires newer version of libcurl, which is not available in standard centos repos. Try to find an rpm for rhel 5, not for Fedora.

Comment: @Thomas Do you have the EPEL and RPMFusion repositories on the yum configuration? It's quite difficult to get "consumer" software like Chrome, which target distributions with faster updates like Fedora, without them. Try adding both. One of them probably have a newer version of libcurl like the one you need.

Comment: @Thomas There's a prebuilt repository for Chromium over here (http://www.linux-powered.com/~ryoji.kamei/ChromiumCentOS5.xhtml). You could give it a try.

Comment: @Thomas - Okay, it seems like your probably best off skipping Chrome... https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=23746

Comment: @Thomas - I downloaded a newer version of licurl, and you can't install the rpm without significant dependencies on Centos 5. You can't just add the libraries to /usr/lib, either. Chrome may run on Centos 6, but I'm not set up to test it. Given that you seem (no offense) to be relatively new to Linux, I suggest that you use a distro other than Centos if you want to use more recently developed apps like Chrome. You could use Fedora or Ubuntu to have something at the leading edge of development.

Comment: @Joe Internet. Thank you for testing and letting me know that the rpm which has an updated libcurl library won't run without further dependencies. As you've mentioned this task will be quite a feat for me to accomplish at this stage; and so I'm letting go. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

for first time you need install this Lib sudo yum install libXScrnSaver
I hed your problem and next time I installed this lib.end OK

Answer (score 0):

In the version available in June 2022, the following command installed the dependencies needed for the Chrome RPM:

```
yum -y install liberation-fonts vulkan*
```